# How to insert string "av" between vowels JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am writing a function which takes a string and should return modified string by adding "av" between every vowel in the string unless a vowel is proceed by another vowel.
Her is my code but it doesn't work how I expect

```
text = text.toLowerCase()
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i += 1) {
    text = text.replace(/([aeiou])([aeiou])/g, 'av')
 }
 return text
}
```

It returns "codingame" instead "cavodavingavamave"

Comment: You need to insert `'av'` between e.g. `'c'` and `'o'`, not between 'two vowels next to each other'.

Comment: is my regular expression is wrong?

Comment: It will change `'aiuao'` to `'avavo'`

Comment: You don't need that loop `replace()` with a `g`lobal flag will get every match. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73206155/2813224)

Comment: I changed, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps like this `[^aeiou\s](?=[aeiou])` see https://regex101.com/r/mKKuKk/1 and replace with the match followed by av `$&av`

Answer (score 1):

Try `/(?<=[^aeiou])(?=[aeiou][^aeiou])/gm`

1. Lookbehind - must NOT match if preceded by vowels
2. Lookahead - must be followed by a vowel and a non-vowel.

Lookarounds matches anything before and after a,e,i,o,u but doesn't include it in the returned match.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/COIzYw/3)

```js
const str = `codingame look`;

const rgx = new RegExp(/(?<=[^aeiou])(?=[aeiou][^aeiou])/, 'g');

let result = str.replace(rgx, 'av');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it works with simple text but if text has vowel by vowel it doesn't work((

Comment: Oh ok, just a sec

Comment: now all tests fail 
```Fail
Found:    "cavodavingavame"
Expected: "cavodavingavamave"```

Comment: Take a look at the snippet click the "run code" button, it gets the expected

Comment: I know, but my tests don't work(( how I could insert to word look just 1 "av"? I think tests want it.

Comment: How are you testing? The word "look" is skipped over because it meets one of the criteria "vowels that are adjacent do not match."

Comment: I have automatic tests in coding game web site

Comment: Did you mean this isn't a match: `lavook` but this a match: `loavok` ? If so, remove the first set of parenthesis so it'll be: `(?=[aeiou][^aeiou])`

Comment: I don't understand the tests in the game, here it works but there no. Thank you for the help!